# DNSBL: blocklist.wrongly.used.as.a.rhsbl.spamhaus.org

Tags: администрирование, dns

У меня есть несколько mail-серверов и я периодически проверяю их наличие во всяких блэк листах. Делаю я это простым **[скриптом](https://github.com/andreasf/check-dnsbl)** раз в сутки, смысл которого просто выполнять `nslookup ip_address OR domain`.

Начала появляться проблема с `zen.spamhaus.org` . По какой-то непонятной для меня причине, некоторые домены начинают резолвиться в спамхаусе непродолжительное время после использования скрипта, но при этом при проверке через сайт spamhaus.org - всё чисто. Резолвятся они следующим образом:

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.domain.net.zen.spamhaus.org    canonical name = blocklist.wrongly.used.as.a.rhsbl.spamhaus.org.
Name:   blocklist.wrongly.used.as.a.rhsbl.spamhaus.org
Address: 127.0.0.2
```

Что означает "blocklist.wrongly.used.as.a.rhsbl.spamhaus.org"? Полагаю я что-то не так делаю, но я не могу по этому поводу найти ни инфы в гугле, ни у spamhaus, и конечно же они не отвечают на вопросы в почту. Надеюсь кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и сможет объяснить что с этим делать?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что спамхаус ругается, потому что он не RHSBL, а IP-блэклист

Comment: Я и сам об этом думал, просто лень было скрипт менять, придётся добавить туда сет IP_LOOKUP_ONLY, занести туда zen и поменять немного условие в main. Ладно, попробую, эхх.

Comment: Вроде больше проблема не повторялась, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как показала практика, `zen.spamhaus.org` ожидает только IP-адреса, но не DNS-имена. С одной стороны логично, но с другой - у них же есть `dbl.spamhaus.org` при запросе IP-адреса у которого, тот сразу отвечает **[адресом указанным в FAQ](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20DBL)**, где написано, что IP-адреса указывать нельзя, всегда. Но zen почему-то только в некоторых случаях и в FAQ про это ни слова. В общем, надеюсь этот ответ проиндексирует гугл и коллеги не будут тратить время на эту проблему.